# openTK migrating to Windows 7 wrong graphics

Tags: c++, opengl, windows-7, opentk

I'm not 100% sure if the problem is with openTK but it is the most probable thing.

I made a project in a computer with Windows XP (x32), MVS 08 with windows fomrs and OpenTK and OpenGL and everything was working perfectly. But for other problems I needed to format the computer and install Windows 7 (x32). 
After installing all the libraries that I needed for developing the project I run it and the computer couldn't open OpenTK. 1000 warnings in the compilation. After installing and uninstalling OpenTK in different directories and so I finally managed to make it work but when executing the application the graphic part is not working properly.

I have 3 OpenGLControllers in with I draw some different plots and so but they are not always working and they are not always full drawn and sometimes it just crashes! 
I have updated my drivers, looked for newer versions of everything but nothing changes.

The compiler warnings are the same since the XP (I  have some warning but nothing to do with the graphic part of the project)

sometimes when crasesh I have the following exception: 'System.AccessViolationException  (note that it doesn't always crash nor always give an exception)

There are 3 GL controllers, only one working properly. When is time for drawing the other don't work or it just breaks

It seems that it only draws properly 1 GLcontroller at a time

It is something that happens with openTK in Windows 7. This problem is usual with Aero theme activated in Windows 7, but I have it disabled and the problem persists.

Comment: I can understand your frustration, but we're not psychic. Can you reproduce a **minimal** example, explain why it's incorrect, and post the code and result image? This is way too vague.

Comment: Sorry, you are right, I was posting this specially wondering if somebody has had the same trouble and knows the solution... This post was a shot in the dark.
I cannot thing in a propper code example, I have a huge proyect and I use several OpenGL and OpenTK functionalities. I will post an image showing the result anyway. Thanks for the feedbak

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It happens that there are several problems with OpenTK and Windows 7.
Usually just disabling the aero theme work for solving the problem, but in my case more than that was required. I changed the GPU of my computer from intel Q33 to nvidia Gforce 430 (a much better one) and now it wors perfectly (well even better than before).

If somebody has the problem please don't forget to check the latest drivers for the GPU, sometimes it works just updating.